# Migrating HTTP-Push technology "Reliable Secure Profile" to Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, comet, push-notification, reliable-secure-profile

I'm looking at [this WCF sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818238.aspx) on HTTP push and want to move this long-polling approach into Azure.

What considerations would need to be taken?

Would I need to create a custom synchronization context?

Comment: I am also interested in this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do server to client push over http, I would recommend SignalR.

Take a look at www.signalr.net and github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

also take a look of a sample at

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29

and

http://www.flyersoft.net/post/2012/05/16/Integration-with-911-dispatch-center-using-Azure-and-SignalR-(part-1).aspx